# Pythonic way to check logics

Tags: python, algorithm, coding-style

What I have found so far in many cases python code for checking business logic or any other logic is some thing like below(simplified):

```
user_input = 100
if user_input == 100:
    do_something()
elif user_input > 100:
    do_sth_different()
else:
    do_correct()
```

When a new logic need to be checked what new python programmer(like me) do just add a new bock in elif...

What is pythonic way to check a bunch of logic without using a long chunk of if else checking?

Thanks.

Comment: It usually depends on what you are ultimately trying to do.

Comment: Can you give a longer example? The example you've given can't be simplified much.

Comment: suppose I have business logic to checking for different clients,for each clients I have to check certain values.Its a long branch of if else then,is there any pythonic way to do it?

Comment: What sort of checks? Are they always equality checks on the same field? Range checks? Regular expressions? Or do the fields or type of check vary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common way is just a line of elifs, and there's nothing really wrong with that, in fact, the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) says to use elifs as a replacement for switches. However, another really popular way is to create a dictionary of functions:

```
functions = {100:do_something,101:do_sth_different}
user_input = 100
try:
    functions[user_input]()
except KeyError:
    do_correct()
```

This doesn't allow for your given `if user_input > 100` line, but if you just have to check equality relationships and a generic case, it works out nicely, especially if you need to do it more than once.

The try except case could be replaced by explicitly calling get on the dictionary, using your generic function as the `default` parameter:

```
functions.get(user_input,do_correct)()
```

If that floats your boat.

Comment: +1 for "there's nothing wrong with elif's". Some logic simply requires a long chain of conditional checks. Other times, if the checks are repetitive, there may be a shortcut.

Answer (score -1):

Aside from the fact that the way you're doing it is probably the best way, you could also write it as:

```
user_input = 100

do_something() if user_input == 100 else
do_sth_different() if user_input > 100 else
do_correct()
```

Comment: -1 This doesn't follow PEP-8.

Comment: @jamylak: Which part? Care to explain how it violates it?

Comment: The original code is formatted correctly, adding backslashes like this is unnecessary and just makes it less readable by not following the standard structure. So it doesn't help imo since the question is not really being answered.

Comment: @jamylak: you're right, the ``\ `` s are redundant. I didn't have an interpreter to test with. I still don't see how this violates PEP-8.

Comment: Doesn't violate it but it doesn't follow their recommendations whereas the original question did. Also doing this doesn't help, it's just unnecessary, that's what I meant.

Comment: @jamylak: Not seeing anything saying that the alternate use of `if` should be avoided.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the more readable way would be preferred, rather than this one which removes the indent making it less readble.